# System slowdown persists despite normal Task Manager and Performance monitor readings

Tags: performance, windows-11, task-manager

My system experienced a slowdown during the OBS Studio video recording.
However, upon reviewing Task Manager and Performance metrics,
no apparent cause for the system freeze was found.
What might be causing this slowdown?
Are there alternative tools to investigate the underlying issue?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if OBS is using CPU encoding? Or GPU? There is a spike in the GPU in the graph in Task Manager, but not sure if that is what causes the slowdown.

Were you experiencing a stuttering? Or just felt bogged down.

The OBS Documentation does outline some steps to diagnose [GPU Overload](https://obsproject.com/wiki/GPU-overload-issues) Otherwise, you can try their more [General Performance](https://obsproject.com/wiki/General-Performance-and-Encoding-Issues) issues doc.

I've found usually laptops have minor/major slowdowns, and usually some component is just "catching up" to a workload. Hope this helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).